# Navigating About, Experience, etc. sections

Tags: html, css

```
<header>
    <div class="menu-toggler">
        <div class="bar half start"></div>
        <div class="bar half"></div>
        <div class="bar half end"></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="top-nav" role='navigation'> 
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#services" class="nav-link">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#experience" class="nav-link">Experience</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="landing-text">
        <h1>Ali Temel</h1>
        <h6>Junior Front-End Developer</h6>
    </div>
</header>
```

Dear Stackoverflow users,

This my very first question. I am an intended web developer. I really tried to link my sections but i cannot jump into section when i click Experience or About section. I appreciate for your help. This is an awesome community. Now i can get a chance to sign up.

https://github.com/alitemel89/personalwebsite-v1

Sincerely,

Ali

Comment: You need another element in the DOM that is associated with the # reference you are setting. Or well, if you are trying to access another page within the same directory then it should be /experience, not #experience.

Answer (score 2):

In order for anchor links to work the structure needs to be like this:

```html
<a href="#about">About</a>

<div id="about">About content</div>
```

Check this for more fancy stuff related to this.
https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code. The problem is that the menu screen doesn't go away.
For example,
When you click on the #about button it goes to the about section but the problem is that your overlay doesn't go away.

-You have to make it, so on click the overlay goes away.

-Your syntax for moving sections is good no need to change that

Comment: $(".top-nav ul li a").click(function() {
    $(".top-nav").hide();
});

Comment: Thank you so much i add the code above in my main.js